# Delaying Render of root component in React errors w/ Hot Reloading

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, webpack-hmr

I need to delay the root app component until my redux store autoHydrates using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). But using this code causes error in development when using Hot Reloading:

```
const App = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Provider store = {store}>
        {getRoutes(checkAuth, history)}
      </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    )

class AppProvider extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { rehydrated: false }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    persistStore(store, {storage: localforage}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.rehydrated) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
      <App />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppProvider/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

If I change it to just this, It works(no error at Hot reloading):

```
const App = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Provider store = {store}>
        {getRoutes(checkAuth, history)}
      </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    )

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I tried something using process.env.NODE_ENV to check if its 'production' or 'development' so I can run the above code snippets conditionally, however, for some reason it still causes that error if I add the stateful component snippet in the condition to only run if process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
**I get the following errors when i change something in a component that render in HomeConatiner:**

> warning.js:36 Warning: React.createElement:
>   type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a
>   string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
>   Check the render method of `HomeContainer`.
>
> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. Check the render method of `HomeContainer`.(…)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `persistStore` function in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.